# Dot Product of a Vector and a point?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

The definition of the Plane $\pi$ says that given a point $A$ $\in \pi$ and a normal vector $\vec{n}$ a point $P \in \pi$ if and only if $\vec{AP} \cdot \vec{n} = 0$, from that we can get $\vec{n} \cdot P - \vec{n} \cdot A = 0$.

Now my doubt is, can we have Dot Product between a vector and a point? Or isn't that a point? What am I missing?

Comment: If it helps, you can think of a point instead as a vector from the origin to the point. E.g. the point $(1,3)=(1,3)-(0,0)$, so the point $(1,3)$ is also the vector from the point $(0,0)$ to $(1,3)$

Comment: Points and vectors(in $\mathbb{R}^n$, or for that matter, in any vector space) are two sides of the same medaillon (I don't even know whether that is an english saying..), note that formally they are completely the same. However, we intuitively like to think about vectors as algebraic objects, and of points as geometric objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you distinguish points and vectors (i.e. consider them elements of different sets) and don't introduce the product of a point with a vector (which would indeed be a strange thing to introduce in that case), it just means that you cannot apply the distributive law. That is, you cannot rewrite $\vec n\cdot (P-A)$ as $\vec n\cdot P - \vec n\cdot A$.

However the more common way to deal with it is to select an arbitrary point $O$, called origin, and then to identify all points with their "location vectors" $\vec P = P - O$ (obviously, $\vec O = O - O = \vec 0$). Now of course $\vec n\cdot \vec P$ is well defined, although in general not a meaningful quantity to calculate in isolation, as its value depends on the arbitrary choice of $O$. However $\vec n\cdot \vec P - \vec n\cdot\vec A$ does not depend on the choice of origin and therefore is a meaningful quantity to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that $\vec{AP} = P-A$ is defined as the vector which extends from $A$ to $P$.